# Quill/React Quill выбор языка в code-block или как заставить его хорошо работать с highlight.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highlighting

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки!!!

С недавнего времени я начал использовать React Quill в своём учебном проекте на React. И тут же столкнулся с проблемой такого рода.
При использовании вставки кода нет возможности выбрать на каком языке этот самый блок кода есть. То есть отображение в редакторе с подсветкой синтаксиса а уже при выводе на странице он отображается как plaintext.
Думал решить эту проблему с помощью конфигурации Highligh.js но что то не получается.

Подскажите верное решение пожалуйста? Может кто то сталкивался с этим или порекомендуйте чего.
Заранее благодарен за ваши ответы.